# Something unexpected happened copying system files for Windows (c:\windows\system32)

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio, file

```
    #define FILE_NAME_MAX_SIZE 512 
    #define buf_len 5   
std::string szFileData;
char file_name[FILE_NAME_MAX_SIZE + 1] = {0};
char databuf[buf_len + 1] = {0};
//printf("------------------\nEnter the file name to transfer:\n");
//scanf("%s",&file_name);
//printf("------------------\n");
int i = 1, unReadLen = 0;
int count = 0;
//----------------------------------------- 
 
FILE* fp = fopen("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe", "rb");
FILE*fp2 = fopen("C:\\Users\\OS\\Desktop\\aa.exe", "wb");
//------------------------------------------
if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("File:%s Not Found!", file_name);
}


else 
       {
    while (1) 
                    {
            fseek(fp, unReadLen, SEEK_SET);
            count = fread(databuf,1, buf_len, fp);                                  
            unReadLen += count *1;  

            printf("count:%d\n", count);
            printf("unReadLen:%d\n", unReadLen);
            printf("%d:%s\n", i++, databuf);

            fwrite(databuf, 1, count, fp2);
            szFileData.append(databuf);

            memset(databuf, 0, sizeof(databuf));
           if (count < buf_len) 
           {
            printf("end\n"); fclose(fp); fclose(fp2); break; 
           }
           }
  }
```

When you copy a file from your system directory to your desktop, the file size changes, but the copied file works
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYavx.png)

Using cmd to execute the copy command on the file the file size is the same
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlF1J.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjsuL.png)

Comment: Pop quiz: how does `szFileData.append(databuf);` know how many characters from `databuf` to append to `szFileData` (whose final size's difference from the actual file is apparently what you're asking about). Once you do your research and figure out how `append()` magically knows how many character to append to the `std::string`, you will simultaneously figure out this Scooby-Doo mystery! (It will also be very helpful to realize that there are many `00` bytes in the copied binary).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Not the problem. Nothing looks at szFileData.

Comment: A friendly wager, @Joshua, that it is. The shown code is not a [mre], that you can cut/paste, ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and allegedly reproduce the issue. This is not the real code, but altered code, there's no `main`, etc... The real code is near certain to have something that dumps the size of `szFileData`, or something along those lines. In any case, that `append()` will not do what the questioner thinks it will do.

Comment: Why have you tagged the C++ code with C?

Comment: szFileData.append(databuf);      I just dumped the file data for convenience later use;   It does not affect new files written.   After annotation code, the size of the new file (aa.exe) created through the file handle of the file (fp2) does not match the size of the original file (calc.exe), as described in my question.

Comment: And the win32 api copyfile interface copies the file size and the original file is not the inequable,So it may not be a problem with the method implementation

Comment: What does Windows do to protect it (c:\ Windows \system32\***)?  As a result, the content data cannot be obtained consistent with the original file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @hahaha1144 Are you using x86 project or x64 project?

Comment: x86 , Found the reason is windows 64-bit system file redirection caused

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Looks like you lost the wager. If you remember the VS default is x86 you could have found it, as could I. But we both missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the reason is windows 64-bit system file redirection caused

Answer (score 1):

This code is dodgy:

```
           if (count < buf_len)
```

Replace it with

```
           if (count <= 0)
```

You might get a short read for no reason at all.

I suspect this isn't the actual problem but this should be fixed *first* to get it out of analysis as the possible problem.

Comment: You will not get a short read from plain files. And especially when using `fread()`. Not true.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I have. He's got a weird buffer size making it more likely too.